# New Line Between Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have tried searching multiple time on how to format java swing elements multiple times, but I can't seem to find anything. I have tried to learn the grid bag layout but it is all too complicated. Could someone please tell me how to space swing components with Swing? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Format_Swing_Elemnts {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
JLabel title = new JLabel("Bridge Settings:");
title.setFont(font);
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Number of Bars: "); 
JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Deck Elevation: "); 
JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Height of arch: "); 
JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Height of Pier: "); 
JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Cabel Anchorage: ");    
JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Concrete Type: ");  
final JLabel lM1 = new JLabel("meters");
final JLabel lM2 = new JLabel("meters");
final JLabel lM3 = new JLabel("meters");
final JRadioButton p1RB1 = new JRadioButton("Standard Abutments");
final JRadioButton p1RB2 = new JRadioButton("Arch Abutments");
final JRadioButton p2RB1 = new JRadioButton("No Pier (one span)");
final JRadioButton p2RB2 = new JRadioButton("Pier (two spans)");
final JRadioButton p3RB1 = new JRadioButton("No Cable Anchorage");
final JRadioButton p3RB2 = new JRadioButton("One Cable Anchorage");
final JRadioButton p3RB3 = new JRadioButton("Two Cable Anchorage");
final JRadioButton p4RB1 = new JRadioButton("Meduim Strength Concrete");
final JRadioButton p4RB2 = new JRadioButton("High Strength Concrete");
ButtonGroup p1 = new ButtonGroup();
p1.add(p1RB1);
p1.add(p1RB2);
ButtonGroup p2 = new ButtonGroup();
p2.add(p2RB1);
p2.add(p2RB2);
ButtonGroup p3 = new ButtonGroup();
p3.add(p3RB1);
p3.add(p3RB2);
p3.add(p3RB3);
ButtonGroup p4 = new ButtonGroup();
p4.add(p4RB1);
p4.add(p4RB2);

final SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 1);
final JSpinner numberBars = new JSpinner(model);
final JSpinner deckElevation = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(24, 0, 24, 4));
final JSpinner archHeight = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(4, 4, 24, 4));
final JSpinner pierHeight = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 24, 4));
JFormattedTextField tf1 =       ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)deckElevation.getEditor()).getTextField();
tf1.setEditable(false);
JFormattedTextField tf2 =  ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)archHeight.getEditor()).getTextField();
tf2.setEditable(false);
JFormattedTextField tf3 = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)pierHeight.getEditor()).getTextField();
tf3.setEditable(false);

JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
JButton continueB = new JButton("Continue");

JPanel format2 = new JPanel();

format2.add(title);
//New line
format2.add(l1);
format2.add(numberBars);
//New line
format2.add(l2);
format2.add(deckElevation);
format2.add(lM1);
//New line
format2.add(p1RB1);
format2.add(p1RB2);
format2.add(l3);
format2.add(archHeight);
format2.add(lM2);
//New line
format2.add(p2RB1);
format2.add(p2RB2);
format2.add(l4);
format2.add(pierHeight);
format2.add(lM3);
//New line
format2.add(l5);
format2.add(p3RB1);
format2.add(p3RB2);
format2.add(p3RB3);
//New line
format2.add(l6);
format2.add(p4RB1);
format2.add(p4RB2);
//New line
format2.add(quit);
format2.add(continueB);

JFrame part2Window = new JFrame("Part 2 - Adjust your settings");
part2Window.add(format2);
part2Window.setSize(290, 365);
part2Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
part2Window.setVisible(true);
part2Window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
part2Window.setResizable(false);
part2Window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: How about to try with MigLayout: http://www.miglayout.com/ Its simple to use.

Comment: You can set empty border around the container (for example, `JPanel`) that holds the swing components.

Comment: Without a concrete example, it's hard to help you directly. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). In all cases, it all comes down to you using LayoutManager's and appropriate nesting. GridBagLayout is actually not that hard (you just have to compare this to an enhanced HTML table), but again without a concrete case, I can't direct you. Always a good place to start from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also found an easier way using the Grid Layout that is much simpler than the Mig Layout. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2):

I improvised a bit with that `spacer` label. I hope that some experienced users won't be mad ;). But I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MyFormat extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel spacer, bridgeSet, numOfBars, deckElev, meters, heightOfArch, heightOfPier,
    cabelAnch, concreteType;

    SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 1);
    JSpinner numberBars = new JSpinner(model);
    JSpinner deckElevation = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(24, 0, 24, 4));
    JSpinner archHeight = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(4, 4, 24, 4));
    JSpinner pierHeight = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 24, 4));

    JRadioButton standAbut = new JRadioButton("Standard Abutments");
    JRadioButton archAbut = new JRadioButton("Arch Abutments");

    JRadioButton noPier = new JRadioButton("No Pier (one span)");
    JRadioButton pier = new JRadioButton("Pier (two spans)");

    JRadioButton noCabAnch = new JRadioButton("No Cable Anchorage");
    JRadioButton oneCabAnch = new JRadioButton("One Cable Anchorage");
    JRadioButton twoCabAnch = new JRadioButton("Two Cable Anchorage");

    JRadioButton medStrCon = new JRadioButton("Meduim Strength Concrete");
    JRadioButton highStrCon = new JRadioButton("High Strength Concrete");

    JButton continueBtn = new JButton("Continue");
    JButton quitBtn = new JButton("Quit");

    public MyFormat() {
        super("Adjust your settings");
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        panel.add(bridgeSet = new JLabel("Bridge settings:"), "wrap");
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(numberBars, "span, grow");
        panel.add(numOfBars = new JLabel("Number of bars:"));
        panel.add(numberBars, "span, grow");
        panel.add(deckElev = new JLabel("Deck elevation: "));
        panel.add(deckElevation);
        panel.add(meters = new JLabel("meters"), "wrap");
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(standAbut, "span, grow");
        panel.add(archAbut, "span, grow");
        panel.add(heightOfArch = new JLabel("Height of arch: "));
        panel.add(archHeight);
        panel.add(meters = new JLabel("meters"), "wrap");
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(noPier, "span, grow");
        panel.add(pier, "span, grow");
        panel.add(heightOfPier = new JLabel("Height of pier: "));
        panel.add(pierHeight);
        panel.add(meters = new JLabel("meters"), "wrap");
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(cabelAnch = new JLabel("Cable anchorage:"),"wrap");
        panel.add(noCabAnch,"span, grow");
        panel.add(oneCabAnch,"span, grow");
        panel.add(twoCabAnch,"span, grow");
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(concreteType = new JLabel("Concrete type: "),"wrap");
        panel.add(medStrCon,"span, grow");
        panel.add(highStrCon,"span, grow");
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(continueBtn);
        panel.add(quitBtn);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyFormat mf = new MyFormat();
                mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                mf.pack();
                mf.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                mf.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

P.S. Used layout: [MigLayout](http://sourceforge.net/projects/miglayout/)

Comment: Personally, I think that's a valid concept to have in your toolkit. I prefer insets from grid bag layout, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Can you explain what "span", "grow" and "warp" mean? And is the mig layout in Java SE? Or do I have to download it? Thanks.

Comment: @user1832583 You have to download it, I left you link ("P.S. Used layout: MigLayout"). Meaning of "span", "wrap" and "grow" you can find on website which link I left you in my comment just below your question. Visit that site and click on "Quick start guide" button. If this helped you consider to accept my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it with a GUI editor like [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/index.html) or [WindowBuilderPro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) from google for eclipse? It's a lot easyer with an editor like this and also a good way to learn how the different layouts work out together. Hope this helps.

Comment: Honestly, this would be my last adivice to give. Using GUI-builder without understanding the basics behind is the best way to create problematic GUI's.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: it can also work the other way round: I would never have understood GridBagLayout that good if it wasn't for the NetBeans GUI editor. Having the possibility to immediately see the effect of changing a property helps a lot. And once it's done you can look at the code and see how everything fits together.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) with vertical orientation when GridBag feels like overkill.