# How to align all jPanels within a jPanel to the left?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

Hey I'm attempting to align all panels within a panel to the left of the larger panel.

here is a picture of what I'm currently faced with:

[image: Box panel layout]

For the master panel (the one that contains all other panels - I shall call it the master!)
I'm using the following code when creating it:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

For each of the panels within it I'm also using the BoxLayout, but I've tried things like [jpanel].setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT) on each panel but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

:)

edit: for the "Dimensions of box(m):" label, is there any way of aligning that to the top of the panel it's contained in?  It's in a panel of its own.

edit:  Once fixed:

[image: JPanel problem once fixed]

Solution below, thanks all for your help :)

Comment: by the way, i know it looks stupid at the moment with each panel having a border.  I only put them there so I could actually see where the panels are :)

Comment: Use `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`. Have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more information

Comment: Sidenote: Are you using `JLabel`'s to set results?

Comment: 1) *"..each panel having a border. .. so I could actually see where the panels are"*  Very smart.  +1 for the simple and instructive GUI layout 'sanity check'.  :)  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  3) As a user, I would prefer to see the labels aligned left, while the values are all aligned in a separate column on the right.  A tabular layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of possibilities, depending on you over all needs.

All I've done here is used compound panels and using `GridBagLayout` to adjust the layouts

[image]

```
public class BadLayout03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadLayout03();
    }

    public BadLayout03() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new MasterPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MasterPane extends JPanel {

        public MasterPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new DimensionsPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new ColorPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new ReinforementPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new SealableTopPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new CardGradePane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new QuantityPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new OrderPricePane(), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class DimensionsPane extends JPanel {

        public DimensionsPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Dimensions of box (m):"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("Length: 33.0"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Width: 3.0"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Height: 3.0"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ColorPane extends JPanel {

        public ColorPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Colour :"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("0"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ReinforementPane extends JPanel {

        public ReinforementPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Reinforcement :"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("None"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class SealableTopPane extends JPanel {

        public SealableTopPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Selable top :"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("No"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class CardGradePane extends JPanel {

        public CardGradePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Grade of card:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("1"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class QuantityPane extends JPanel {

        public QuantityPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Quantity:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("1"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class OrderPricePane extends JPanel {

        public OrderPricePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("Order price:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("$558.9"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This one goes to favorites. :)

Comment: Ah great!  Thanks for all your help @MadProgrammer, definitely using this :)  Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class PanelAlignment extends JFrame {
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();

    JLabel dimOfBox, rein, seaTop;

    public PanelAlignment() {
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout());

        firstPanel.add(dimOfBox = new JLabel("Dimensions of box (m): "));
        firstPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        contentPane.add(firstPanel,"wrap");

        secondPanel.add(rein = new JLabel("Reinforcement: "));
        secondPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        contentPane.add(secondPanel,"wrap");

        thirdPanel.add(dimOfBox = new JLabel("Sealable top: "));
        thirdPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        contentPane.add(thirdPanel,"wrap");
        add(contentPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PanelAlignment pa = new PanelAlignment();
                pa.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                pa.pack();
                pa.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And you will get something like this:

[image]

I recently answered on similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434888/new-line-between-swing-components/13436241#13436241)

Good luck! :)

Comment: That's such an informative answer!  Thanks for taking the time to create that for me, unfortunately in university we can't download extras for Java; I'd have to download the MigLayout :/  

Great answer though, I'll get in touch with my lecturer and see if i can use it, thanks again, If I don't receive a different answer I'll mark this one as the answer :)

Thank you

Comment: By the way, I am using JLabels to set results, is that a bad idea?  (First time using Java GUI!)

Comment: @OmarQassem Yes Omar! Using `JLabel`'s to set results is a bad idea! If your goal is to protect your values from editing, you could use `JTextField` and to call setEditable(false); method. If you can't use MigLayout consider to accept MadProgrammers answer. Good luck again!

Comment: Ah I managed to do it myself: 

Instead of having one panel for all panels, I have two panels in the main panel now (components aligned on x axis) - one for containing the name of what is to be displayed (colour, grade of card etc) and in the other panel the actual results.  Each of the two panels that contain the labels (soon to be JTextFields) have their components aligned in the Y axis.  

All is well in the house of Omar!

Thank you for your help, and I'll be downloading MigLayout :)